# How to write a program that prints the sum of ten numbers that the user has to enter

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to write a program in Python that prints the sum of ten numbers that the user has to enter.
Additionally the program must control the user's input and check if the user has entered a number or a string

Somehow it must be solved with the loop methode.

I tried it with:

```py
sum = 0
try:
    for i in range (0, 10):
        a = int(input("Enter a number: "))
        sum += a
    print("\nThe sum is:", sum)
except ValueError:
    print("User entered string")
```

The code is working, but I don't understand how to check after every input if the user has entered a number or a string

Comment: This is clearly an assignment and you are asking strangers to do it for you. This is not the place for that, you're gonna get downvoted a lot. It's not a hard problem, you should put some time in and try to solve it, then post your code and ask for advice.

Comment: Hi Lucas! I'm sorry if that came out wrong. That wasn't my intention, of course I tried to solve it but didn't reach the desired goal.

Comment: That's ok, I just answered with my take on your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you wrote it, the script will end after the first error.

If you'd like to check for a string, display a message and still ask for input, you could try something like this:

```
i = 0
total = 0
while i < 10:
    try:
        a = int(input(f'Enter a number (position {i}): '))
        total += a
        i += 1
    except ValueError:
        print('You entered a string. Try again.')
print(f'\nThe sum is: {total}')
```

It will run until `i` reaches 10, but we only increment `i` when the input is valid.

Also, avoid using a variable named `sum` since it's already a native function in Python.

Feel free to ask anything, hope it helps.

Comment: Thank's alot! That's what I was looking for. What does the 'f' in int(input(f'Enter a number(position {i})): ")) mean?

Comment: It's called "Literal String Interpolation", or more commonly "F-strings". If you put "f" before a literal string, the expressions inside braces are replaced with their values. Read more here: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/

Answer (score 0):

```
list_number = []                                                                                                                                                          
while len(list_number) < 10:                                
    try:                                                  
        u_number = int(input("Please enter a number: "))    
        list_number.append(u_number)                      
    except ValueError:                                   
        print("Value entered is not an int.")              
print(sum(list_number))
```

First it creates an empty list.

Then there is a while condition where the program runs till the length of the list reaches 11.

The program saves the input of the user in the list if it is an integer. If not there is ValueError.

At the end the sum of the list is printed

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.